# import python modules recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I am implementing the structure given below:

```
expr =  Name(identifier id, expr_context ctx)
         | Call(expr func, expr* args, keyword* keywords)
```

Regarding my code structure, I have scripts named as `expr.py`, `Name.py` and `Call.py`.

`expr.py` contains

```
from Name import *
from Call import *
...
def visit_expr_node(node):
    # other code
    result = traverse_call_node(args) # from Call.py
```

the function `visit_expr_node` is just called from the another module.

Sice the grammar shows that the `Call` could have `expr` type arguments, therefore in the `Call.py` I am also importing `expr.py`, so that it will automatically calls the modules for type `expr`.
The structure of `Call.py` is:

```
from expr import *
...
def traverse_call_node(args):
   if type(args)==expr:
       visit_expr_node(args)
```

But the code is not working and it throws an error in `expr.py`, `NameError: name 'traverse_call_node'` is not defined.

It is sort of a recursive or circular import, I think that's why I am getting the error. Seen other examples here but didn't find a solution yet. Any ideas how can I over come this issues or any idea how can I implement the structure give above in a better way? Thanks for the help.

Comment: My first instinct is that you are just defining too many modules.

Comment: May be, this is I also wanted to ask, could there be a better way to implement the given structure, because the same type is appearing many times.

Comment: What type is expr? Could just that be in its own module?

Comment: @quamrana expr is a type, which is the starting point to check the type of module, i.e., ```Name```, ```Call``` etc.

Comment: But what type is it? Is it a class?

Comment: Yes, Its a class.

Comment: So, as a class it could go into its own module. Could the current expr module attach its own functions to that class?

Comment: expr just contains one function and have multiple imports and it is calling functions from other module dynamically, like this: ```globals()[func_name](node)```.

Comment: This is too complicated to diagnose. The next option is for the whole of the Call module to be pasted into the expr module.

Comment: I'll try it, may be you could propose other way of implementing such a structure? actually I am implementing this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html, (the abstract grammar).